# Manual focus lens on fixed focus camera?

Tags: lens, focus, manual-focus

Hello i have bought [this camera](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Compact-Digital-Camera-24MP-4X-Digital-Zoom-3-Rotatable-Screen-Semi-Pro-Photo-Video-Recorder-Camcorder/32785992486.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.7d5e4c4dAxVHqj):

[image]

It is a lens type camera, but it has a FIXED focus. 
I read on the internet that if I buy and put a manual focus lens it will work? 
Is that true ?

If it is true what type of lens should i buy .. i search and search but there are A lot of different types of lens interfaces .. i dont know even what my interface is.. it just screws .. a screw type lens ? (or something like  that)

I can take photos of something if would be helpfull :)

Comment: "It is a lens type camera"... What does that mean? What camera is not a lens type camera?

Comment: @osullic a pinhole-based camera obscora maybe?

Comment: What possessed you to buy such a contraption? That page looks like they just stuck every photography related acronym they could think of on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This camera appears to essentially be a phone camera placed into a body made to look like a compact 'point and shoot' or small advanced compact camera. Most of the "lens" is just window dressing for the tiny lens located in the middle. In some of the product photos there appears to be a flat, screw on "protective" filter in place to make the "lens" look much larger than it actually is.

The optional "lenses" are [screw on adapters that attach in front of the actual lens permanently attached to the camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/41670/15871). They are similar to the add-on "telephoto", "wide angle", and "macro" attachments one can purchase to use on their phone's camera. Such "lenses" are [also available to fit some lower cost SLR lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76495/15871), such as the 18-55mm kit lenses sold with many entry level DSLRs.

When the description says "fixed focus" what it probably means is that the focal length of the embedded lens on the camera has a fixed focal length. Several other clues in the description hint that the description is a less than perfect translation from another language.

The optional "lenses" will probably work about as well as similar attachments made for phone cameras do. I doubt you will have any control over being able to manually focus this camera. It will probably autofocus about like most phone cameras do. After all, what this camera appears to be is basically a phone camera disguised as a compact point and shoot or even a "bridge" camera.

The specific screw-on adapter lenses you would need for this camera have thread sizes of 52mm. They are made to screw onto 52mm threads such as those on the front of your camera. Since these types of adapters are made for use with larger "kit" lenses sold with entry level DSLRs, they might be slightly better quality than the sizes made to adapt to camera phones. Bu then again, they might not be.

Comment: The sad part is that the camera doesn't have auto focus :D 
Everything is in focus. No matter how close or far it is .. :/

Comment: @ToZo It's hard to tell for sure from the description. My guess is that it probably does have AF. The "fixed focus" is most likely a mis-translation of "fixed focal length". Notice that the "zoom" is all digital.

Comment: Well i bought this camera .. its in me :D 
I went trough all settings and didn't see something like that :(

Comment: A camera can be AF only  and have no settings regarding AF. How many phone cameras allow you the opportunity to change an AF setting? That doesn't mean they don't AF, though. What happens when you point the camera at a high contrast target close to the camera? What happens when you point it at a distant high contrast target? Are you saying the camera does not automatically alter the focus distance in such a scenario? Even with a small sensor, I'd be sceptical that the camera would be usable without some focusing mechanism with an aperture of f/2.4 and a 5mm focal length lens.